# Memset Definition and use

Tags: c++, c, function

What's the usefulness of the function `memset()`?.

> **Definition**: Sets the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by ptr to the
>   specified value (interpreted as an unsigned char).

Does this mean it hard codes a value in a memory address?

`memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr)` is the example that I'm trying to understand.

Can someone please explain in a VERY simplified way?

Comment: It is mostly used to initialize structs and arrays.

Comment: so it's like saying array[value]? why not just do it that way though, what's the point of using memset then?

Comment: You can do it like `array[value]` only if you know the value of `value` during compile time (this is C/C++).

Comment: Because you can set all the bytes on the struct/array at the same time. You could do it with a for loop, but memset will perform a lot better.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`memset()` is a very fast version of a relatively simple operation:

```
void* memset(void* b, int c, size_t len) {
    char* p = (char*)b;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != len; ++i) {
        p[i] = c;
    }
    return b;
}
```

That is, `memset(b, c, l)` set the `l` bytes starting at address `b` to the value `c`. It just does it much faster than in the above implementation.

Comment: @Neil: good point - I'm a C++ person and I realized I rely on the conversion. I'll change the code to be both C and C++.

Comment: As coded, your function has implementation defined behavior because `c` might be out of range for the `char` type. You should instead define `p` as `unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)b;`  (the cast is only needed in C++).

Comment: @DietmarKühl How come it does it much faster? How else can it possible do without a loop? Is it using an OS api to do it? And even then it would still require a loop.

Comment: @Nik-Lz: the compiler knows about `memset()` and doesn't need to do any analysis on the arguments and can easily generate vector operations. Admittedly, many compilers will vectorize loops in optimization mode.

Answer (score 45):

`memset()` is usually used to initialise values. For example consider the following struct:

```
struct Size {
    int width;
    int height;
}
```

If you create one of these on the stack like so:

```
struct Size someSize;
```

Then the values in that struct are going to be undefined. They might be zero, they might be whatever values happened to be there from when that portion of the stack was last used. So usually you would follow that line with:

```
memset(&someSize, 0, sizeof(someSize));
```

Of course it can be used for other scenarios, this is just one of them. Just think of it as a way to simply set a portion of memory to a certain value.

Comment: Given the question asking what the point of memset is, this answer is better than the accepted one imho.

Answer (score 11):

`memset` is a common way to set a memory region to 0 regardless of the data type. One can say that `memset` doesn't care about the data type and just sets all bytes to zero.

IMHO in C++ one should avoid doing `memset` when possible since it circumvents the type safety that C++ provides, instead one should use constructor or initialization as means of initializing. memset done on a class instance may also destroy something unintentionally:

e.g.

```
class A
{
public:
  shared_ptr<char*> _p;
};
```

a `memset` on an instance of the above would not do a reference counter decrement properly.

Comment: This answer should be higher up on the list. It is not safe to use memset in C++.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that `serv_addr` is some local or global variable of some `struct` type -perhaps `struct sockaddr`- (or maybe a `class`).

`&serv_addr` is taking the address of that variable. It is a valid address, given as first argument to `memset`. The second argument to `memset` is the byte to be used for filling (zero byte). The last argument to `memset` is the size, in bytes, of that memory zone to fill, which is the size of that `serv_addr` variable in your example.

So this call to `memset` clears a global or local variable `serv_addr` containing some `struct`.

In practice, the *GCC* compiler, when it is optimizing, will generate clever code for that, usually unrolling and inlining it (actually, it is often a builtin, so *GCC* can generate very clever code for it).

Answer (score 2):

It is nothing but setting the memory to particular value.

Here is example code.

Memset(const *p,unit8_t V,unit8_t L) , Here the P is the pointer to target memory, V is the value to the target buffer which will be set to a value V and l is the length of the data.

```
while(L --> 0)
{
    *p++ = V;
}
```

Comment: Nice example of the downto to operator `-->`, but I am highly skeptical about the type of the `L` argument: `unit8_t` should be `size_t`.

Answer (score 2):

memset- set bytes in memory

Synopsis-

```
#include<string.h>
```

void *memset(void *s,int c,size_t n)

Description- **The memset() function shall copy c (converted to an unsigned char) into each of the first n bytes of the object pointed to by s.**
Here for the above function , the memset() shall return s value.

Comment: How does this answer add value to a 4 year old post with 5 other answers?

Comment: I was looking for an answer and I got to know this definition from another source.So thought it would be helpful for other people who are in searching of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful with stl types.

Some are averse to `memset` (i.e. being zero initialized), and you might not realize it until you port your code to another platform.

For example, this struct

```cpp
struct Foo { 
  std::string S;
  ... Lots of other members
};
```

will by chance "survive" being zero-initialized...

```
Foo f;
memset(&f, O, sizeof(Foo));
```

...on most systems (Windows, macOS, Linux with SYSV ABI), and then fail miserably with Linux when using the GNU/Linux ABI.

See [war story](https://github.com/pthom/imgui_bundle/issues/170)