# how to set or initialize default value for all elements of a table or 2d array or multdimentional array

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to set a default nonzero value for all elements of a table or 2d array. array[size]={12} sets first elements only 12 and others are all 0 in a row.But fill(array,array+size,12) sets all elements to 12 in a row only.I could't apply this for 2d array.Is there any way to do this using fill() or any way without direct initialization using double for loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int arra[10][10];//declare 2d array

  for(int k=0;k<10;k++)//takes k's value 10 for 10 rows
     fill(arra,arra+10,45);//select a row and set all columns to 45 didn't work

}
```

array initialization
 http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/array-initialization.html

Comment: You can preferably use [memset()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327155/memset-definition-and-use).

Comment: Don't use a raw array.

Answer (score 4):

For C arrays, you'll probably want to use `memset`. You've marked this as C++, though, so I feel obliged to give a C++ answer:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(10, std::vector<int>(10, 45));
```

This creates a `std::vector` of 10 `std::vector<int>`s of size 10 with each element initialized to 45.

See [here](http://ideone.com/aLe7Ra) for the ideone.

Answer (score 2):

Almost the same way as you would with a 1-dimensional array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    int arr[10][10] = {
        {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10 },
        {  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20 },
        {  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30 },
        {  4,  8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40 },
        {  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50 },
        {  6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60 },
        {  7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70 },
        {  8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80 },
        {  9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90 },
        { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 }
    };

    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        for(int j=0; j<10; ++j) {
            std::cout << std::setw(4) << arr[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

NOTE: The first index does not require a value. In that case the compiler will automatically calculate this index.

```
int arr[][10] = { ... };
```

**EDIT**

An alternative that will avoid a double loop is:

```
## Heading ###include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


int main() {
    int arr[10][10] = {}; // Initializes all values to 0
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i ) arr[i][0] = 12;

    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        for(int j=0; j<10; ++j) {
            std::cout << std::setw(4) << arr[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: But think if array size is 100*100 then how difficult it is to set them indivizually

Answer (score 1):

A solution (not really elegant, I know) can be

```
for ( auto & row : arra )
   for ( auto & elem : row )
      elem = 45;
```

or, using `std::fill()`

```
for ( auto & row : arra )
   std::fill(std::begin(row), std::end(row), 45);
```

---- **EDIT** ----

Full example

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
 {
   int a[10][10];

   // mode A
   for ( auto & row : a )
      for ( auto & elem : row )
         elem = 45;

   // mode B
   for ( auto & row : a )
      std::fill(std::begin(row), std::end(row), 47);

   for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i ) 
    {
      for ( int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; ++j )
         std::cout << '[' << a[i][j] << ']';

      std::cout << '\n';
    }

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `auto` (in that context) is a C++11 feature. Can you show us the error? Added a full example.

Comment: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ffdg.cpp\main.cpp|8|warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]|

Comment: i just past ur added example. run and then this simmilar error happens

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling C++11? According that error, you're compiling C++98. You're using gcc in mingw? You should add `-std=c++11`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not much better than memset, but at least you can specify the value for each int instead of each byte with std::fill used like that:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int arra[10][10];
   std::fill((int*)arra,(int*)arra+sizeof(arra)/sizeof(int),45);

   for (auto& row : arra) {
     for (auto& x : row)
       printf("%d ", x);
     puts("");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

This relies on the array elements being contiguous in memory.

```
45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 
45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 
45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 
45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 
45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 
45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 
45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 
45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 
45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 
45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45
```