# Two dimensional array in c++ initialization to one value

Tags: c++

I have two dimensional char array in c++ and want to give all element one value without using loops 
is there any function to achieve it ?

Comment: If you are using std::array can do: std::array<std::array<char, 3>, 3> arr; Can do : std::fill_n(array, 9, 'a');

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026955/how-to-set-or-initialize-default-value-for-all-elements-of-a-table-or-2d-array-o

Comment: Without any loops what so ever? That's not possible. Without loops in your own source code? Then yes, as shown by the answers. But note that `memset` will have one or more loops in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char demo[5][7];

memset(demo, '\0', sizeof(demo));
```

Based on the provided info, does this do what you want?

Since you're using C++ I'd question to use a native char array, as long as you're not required to and/or needing to use the stack.

Otherwise its idiomatic to use the collection classes provided by the STL.

Adding to the answer as requested, this obviously does what the question asks for: initializing the memory of a char array.

Please see the docs for more information on memset: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset

Comment: Please try to explain *why* it would work. Just posting code without any explanation for people to copy-paste leads to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which is bad.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the way is obvious it's not just about copy and paste it's about using a built in function

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude please remove your comment or state *explicitly* what is missing from your point of view. If you want me to paste more docs, please let me know, but still I'd question why you'd want me to do this.

Comment: @Abdalrahmanshebani & @AlexB I would say it's only obvious if one knows how arrays of arrays (a.k.a. "2d" arrays) are laid out in memory. For many beginners it's not known, and therefore it might not be easy to understand why a single `memset` call could set all elements of all arrays, or why `sizeof` will give the correct size.